# UPDATE statement wrapped in an IF EXISTS block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a DML script that updates a column but I wanted to make sure the column existed first so I wrapped it in a IF EXISTS block

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Client' AND COLUMN_NAME='IsClarityEnabled') 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Client SET IsClarityEnabled = 1 WHERE ClientID = 21
END
```

So the weirdness is that it tries to execute the update even if it fails the condition.  So column doesn't exist and the UPDATE statement runs and I get an error. Why?

Even stranger is that this does work:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Client' AND COLUMN_NAME='IsClarityEnabled') 
BEGIN
    EXEC('UPDATE Client SET IsClarityEnabled = 1 WHERE ClientID = 21')
END
```

Is there something special about an UPDATE command that causes it to behave this way?

Comment: Does this question mean you are using Clarity? If so I feel your pain.

Comment: Yes, Clarity is being used here.  In and of itself, it's not so bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the script will be compiled/parsed, and if the column does not exist, you will have a compile/parse error.

> Invalid column name
>   'IsClarityEnabled'.

Comment: +1, you should note that it doesn't compile the string in the EXEC() until run time, so it does not try to validate the column that does not exist yet.

Comment: That is correct, that is the **Dynamic Sql** you might find reference to

Answer (score 2):

> it tries to execute the update even if it fails the condition

Are you sure? I suspect that what is actually happening is that SQL Server is attempting to *parse* the `UPDATE`, whatever the value of the condition. Since parsing happens before execution, at parse time SQL Server can't 'know' that you have protected this `UPDATE` with a check - the parser only knows that there isn't an `IsClarityEnabled` column on `Client`, and so it complains.

The reason the `EXEC` works as you want is preciely because the string literal isn't processed by the parser. This is the standard way of having scripts that must run against a schema that isn't known until execution time.

Comment: I had assumed it was due the the execution failure but it was the parser failure.