# IF EXISTS not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a re-runnable script

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT * from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA=N'MySchema' and TABLE_NAME=N'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME=N'Column1'))
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Updating'

   UPDATE [Table2] 
   SET Column = 0
   WHERE Id IN (SELECT t2.Id 
                FROM [Table2] t2 
                JOIN [MySchema].[Table1] t1 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId 
                WHERE t1.Column1 = 0)

   ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Table1] DROP COLUMN Column1
END
```

It works the first time, but 2nd time I get the error

> *Invalid column name 'Column1'.*

Any help would be appreciated. I was using `sys.columns` before to check if the column exists. It's for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: When you run SELECT * from information_schema.columns is there a column named column1 in that result set?

Comment: try putting `ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Table1] DROP COLUMN Column1` in a dynamic sql call.

Comment: @KM. . . . You should put the suggestion in an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: Hm... seems to work on 2012. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ba0e/1

Comment: @KM, could you please give an example?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: [No, it doesn't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/548a2/1). Although for some reason the error only happens/is displayed when the offending bit is in the right panel.

Comment: @AndriyM Good catch, strange behavior from SQLfiddle in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE statement wrapped in an IF EXISTS block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586737/update-statement-wrapped-in-an-if-exists-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL is not a batch script, and the parser checks the whole statement before executing it. Therefore, if the column in the sub-select does not exist, the check will fail before execution even starts.

For your code to work, you need to pass the UPDATE and ALTER statements as string to `EXECUTE` or `EXEC sp_executesql`.

See also [Q2586737](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586737/update-statement-wrapped-in-an-if-exists-block?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with splitting your script into batches, you could use the `SET NOEXEC` command.

Set it ON when the column doesn't exist. Put the UPDATE and ALTER TABLE into a separate batch, i.e. separate it from the condition with a `GO`. Put another `GO` and add `SET NOEXEC OFF` if there are other statements in your script that need to be executed, which do not depend on the condition.

For an illustration, this is what I mean:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  from information_schema.columns
  where TABLE_SCHEMA=N'MySchema'
    and TABLE_NAME=N'Table1'
    AND COLUMN_NAME=N'Column1'
)
  SET NOEXEC ON
GO

PRINT 'Updating'

UPDATE [Table2] 
SET Column = 0
WHERE Id IN (SELECT t2.Id 
             FROM [Table2] t2 
             JOIN [MySchema].[Table1] t1 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId 
             WHERE t1.Column1 = 0)

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Table1] DROP COLUMN Column1
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
... -- the rest of the script, if any
```

Comment: I still receive errors when using this approach, [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1177/1)

Comment: @Shaun: Perhaps it's to do with how SQL Fiddle works. I don't have this issue [in dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=256e0edd233caadb01e2e5c328026afa)

Comment: I believe this is because dbfiddle is actually separating the script into physically separate batches based on the GO separator, so each script is only validated after the previous one is run.  In my situation I have one physical script with multiple logical batches (separated by GO statements) and SET NOEXEC does not avoid the error in this case.